# Hover event to occur independently on separate images

Tags: jquery, image, hover

Alright, so I have some code hurr:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo img").hover(function () {
        $("div.show").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Now, it works like a champ.  Except for the fact that it occurs on all images simultaneously.  I tried to find out how to get it to work on each image separately, but I don't have the darnest clue.

What I am trying to do specifically is have a hover event on an image occur only when you hover over that specific image.  When you hover over an image a div pops up with some fancy caption and so on.  However, when I hover on one image all the other images show the same thing (I understand why, just not how to fix it).

I figure it has something to do with adding `this` to it, but I'm new to JQuery and I'm lost.

HTML:

```
<div class="post photo">
    <img src="source" />
    <div class="show">
        <div class="caption">
        Caption
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Share the HTML markup, we can't guess what you are trying to do without some sample markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo img").hover(function () {
        $(this).next("div.show").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 It was a rhetorical question. The HTML code wasn't included in the answer when I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With this you can disregards from what position you have put your "show" div into "post photo" class div :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo img").hover(function () {
        $(this).parent().children("div.show").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```